# Android - Pinch to zoom gesture to enlarge Button

Tags: android

Looking at guides and examples gave me no clear clues on how to perform this:

I am trying to enable such gesture on a `Button` with a custom background (a circle-shaped `Drawable`) so that its size can be increased or decreased within certain ranges. I am trying this but before going any further I'd like to know if this is the right way to proceed and if there is any more effective alternate way to achieve this.

```
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(v.getContext(), new ScaleListener());
private float mScaleFactor=1.f;
private Button MyButtonView;
MyButtonView.setOnTouchListener(this);
isBtn=false;
//...
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(!isBtn) mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));
        //TODO set width = getWidth()*mScaleFactor;
        //TODO set height = getHeight()*mScaleFactor; 
        MyClass.this.MyButtonView.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: can I ask why you want a button to increase the size? It is unconventional to scale a UI element with a gesture. The complete UI is a different store, but only one element?

Comment: Because this UI element represents a portion of surface where some feature is enabled, so I just need to zoom this element.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it but as I said without "training" the user that a zoom works on a button, no user will ever think that he can zoom one...

Comment: @WarrenFaith Think it bigger than a simple button, it is a Button, but it is shown as a circle drawable with a text inside it, so the user knows, even because of the purpose of the application, that he/she has to pinch it to zoom.

Comment: hm ok. I wouldn't use a button than, maybe you should just extend View and implement your own behaviour. I think this approach combined with your above code is the way to go.